# Batch script - calculating md5 hashes for all files in c: drive

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, md5sum

I'm trying to figure out how to setup specific location where I want to start calculating hashes ? Let's say I would like to start calculating md5 hashes for all files on c:\ drive and files included in folders as well.

```
set mypath="C:\"

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%z in (`dir /b /s /a-d /on "%mypath%"`) do md5sum "%%z" >> "C:\Temp\system_hashes.txt"
```

Not sure what is wrong with above code ?

Comment: Why do you have `"`s around ``C:\``?

Comment: yeah my fault, already fixed but still doesn't work.

Comment: What makes you think it's not working? Hint: the `dir` part of the `for` command takes a very long time to finish ...

Comment: ... not to mention each md5sum, given "larger" files.

Comment: But while above function is running, the file system_hashes.txt in path C:\Temp\ is not created. I believe that this file should be created at the beginning, and then any new md5 hash will be written. That is why I'm thinking that it doesn't work. It works for narrow path like C:\folderA or something, but for entire disk like C: looks like suspended. Is there any option to speed up this function ?

Comment: Then for a test don't start at the root but a small folder and result should show up at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
set mypath="C:\"

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%z in (`dir /b /s /a-d /on "%mypath%"`) do certutil -hashfile "%%z" MD5 >> "C:\Temp\system_hashes.txt"
```

You can try it that way I worked too. Make sure you create the temp folder and file in the correct path and name.